# regex to remove text between two strings in TextWrangler

Tags: regex, grep, vcf-vcard, textwrangler

I've searched quite hard for an answer to this.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to remove certain fields in some of my exported vCards which I exported using the Mac's Contacts application via Automator.

I managed to remove those single-line fields such as Birthday and Social Network. However, there is one particular field which is taking up multiple lines which I assume is a base64-encoded version of the original image - the PHOTO field.

This is an example of the start of the field:
`PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUA`

The end varies, so I used the start of the next line as the end:
`CATEGORIES`

The closest I've got was `PHOTO;ENCODING.*CATEGORIES`

Unfortunately, it seems to only select the the first line of the entire chunk.

Is there any way around this? I'm trying to do this in TextWrangler on my Mac.

Comment: I know nothing about textwrangler but in other languages you would need to explicitly tell the regex engine what you are matching is multiline.  For instance, in Perl, you would need `/m` on the end of your regex.  Without `/m`, `.` will not match a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of .* you need :-

```
(.+[\r\n]+).*
```

because . doesn't match linebreak chars.

The pattern in parentheses matches multiple lines consisting of char sequences ending with linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a friend I tried in TextWrangler

```
ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64([^\n]*\n )*[^\n]*\n
```

and it matches each attachment